# Broadcast Functionality in Apache Flink using Java

Tags: dataset, batch-processing, apache-flink

I am trying to implement Apache Flink - broadcasting.. How do we implement broadcasting for datasets using Java.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Flink DataSet API Programming Guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/batch/index.html#broadcast-variables) provides and example on how you can broadcast a dataset in Java:

```
// 1. The DataSet to be broadcasted
DataSet<Integer> toBroadcast = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3);

DataSet<String> data = env.fromElements("a", "b");

data.map(new RichMapFunction<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
      // 3. Access the broadcasted DataSet as a Collection
      Collection<Integer> broadcastSet = getRuntimeContext().getBroadcastVariable("broadcastSetName");
    }

    @Override
    public String map(String value) throws Exception {
      ...
    }
}).withBroadcastSet(toBroadcast, "broadcastSetName"); // 2. Broadcast the DataSet
```